# Is there an interesting example of a chaotic dynamical system on $\widehat{\mathbb{C}}^n$, where $\widehat{\mathbb{C}}$ is the Riemann sphere?

Tags: complex-analysis, dynamical-systems

This is for a mathematical visualization project I'm interested in. I am looking for an example of a chaotic, continuous-time dynamical system on $\widehat{\mathbb{C}}^n$. Here $n$ is arbitrary, but I would also like to hear about examples for specific $n$. I am particularly interested in systems that are highly chaotic: i. e. they generally do not converge to a stable orbit or limit, and are quite "irregular". Topological mixing might be a desirable property. Ideally such a system will be specified by a differential equation and make some use of the complex structure.  I am not very well-versed in dynamical systems, so please excuse me if this comes off as obtuse. Can anyone please provide an example of such a system, or direct me to a reference where I can read about explicit examples of complex dynamical systems along these lines? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think what I am looking for cannot exist by the Poincare-Bendixson theorem. If $M = \widehat{\mathbb{C}}$, a dynamical system $f_t: M^n \to M^n$ gives rise to a dynamical system $g_t: M \to M$ by fixing the last $n-1$ coordinates in the domain and projecting onto the first coordinate in the range, and then the orbit of this is constrained by Poincare-Bendixson. So not interesting enough for my purposes. Oh well… I guess I’ll have to use a pseudorandom setup instead.